# I cant understand why is 9 power 13 does not give a correct answer

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main() {
   printf("The minimum value of LONG = %ld\n", LONG_MIN);
   printf("The maximum value of LONG = %ld\n", LONG_MAX);
   printf("%ld",9*9*9*9*9*9*9*9*9*9*9*9*9);

   return(0);
}
```

Sorry for the basic question but I am currently struggling to assign a large number to a variable even though it is a long int. The result here of `9` power `13` is false. Normally it would be `2541865828329`.

Output :

```
minimum value of LONG = -9223372036854775808                                                                                                    
The maximum value of LONG = 9223372036854775807                                                                                                     
3540156393
```

Comment: Did you switch on warnings? gcc compiler gives warning: Woverflow

Comment: If you turned on warnings when you compile, like using the `-Wall` flag with `gcc`, you'd see a warning like this: `warning: format ‘%ld’ expects argument of type ‘long int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]` on your last `printf`.  Also, an integer overflow warning as well.

Answer (score 4):

The product is actually of `int` type. You should explicitly convert it to long type by suffixing all the multipliers by `LL`.

```
9 * 9 .. => is of type int
9LL * 9LL .. => is of type long long
```

Comment: Since the `*` operator is left-associative, only first `9` can be suffixed.

Comment: @EugeneSh. While that's true, it's good to be explicit rather than depending on automatic conversions.

Comment: @EugeneSh. - I assume this means if I have `int x,y,z;`, that I can do `long long xyz = (long long)x * y * z;` and be ok?  I've always been paranoid, and perhaps over-cast my types.  Which is honestly pretty unreadable with full casts.

Comment: @zzxyz This will become `((long)x * y) * z`. The `x` and `y` will get promoted to long according to promotion rules as the result of their multiplication. Then `z` will get promoted according to the same rule.

Comment: @EugeneSh. - Perfect, that's what I thought `left-associative` should mean :)  Another rule I should have understood completely 5 years ago rather than having vague hunches.

Comment: At least my answer is popular, who cares about votes :D

Answer (score 2):

The program actually has undefined behavior:

- The result is computed as an `int` because all operands in the expression are of type `int`. If type `int` is 32-bit wide, the computation causes arithmetic overflow, which has undefined behavior.
- passing an `int` for `printf` format `%d` has undefined behavior too, especially if type `long` has a different size than type `int`.

Note that 9<sup>13</sup> is larger than 2<sup>31</sup>-1 but smaller than 2<sup>63</sup>-1, so type `long`, which is specified as having at least 31 value bits might not be large enough for this value, causing arithmetic overflow, which has undefined behavior.

Type `long long` is specified as having at least 63 value bits, so it is safe to perform the computation with this type.

The rules for type integer promotion and type conversion are somewhat tricky. You can read section 6.3 of the C Standard for details, just remember that for types `int`, `long` and `long long`, the computation is performed with the type of the larger operand and the result has this type.

All binary arithmetic operators have left to right associativity, which means `a + b + c` is evaluated as `(a + b) + c`. This rule applies to operators with the same precedence level, so `a * b / c` is evaluated as `(a * b) / c`, which does not apply here but is useful to know.

Form the above, we can derive that specifying the first operand of the expression as having type `long long` suffices for the expression to evaluate using `long long` arithmetic and produce a value of type `long long`. The value `9` can be explicitly converted to `long long` with a cast `(long long)9` or with a suffix `9LL`. Note that `9LL` is less confusing than `9ll` (nine ell ell in small case) that can be mis read as `911`.

Here is a corrected program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main() {
   printf("The minimum value of LONG = %ld\n", LONG_MIN);
   printf("The maximum value of LONG = %ld\n", LONG_MAX);
   printf("The minimum value of LONG LONG = %lld\n", LLONG_MIN);
   printf("The maximum value of LONG LONG = %lld\n", LLONG_MAX);
   printf("9**13 = %lld\n", 9LL * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9);
   return 0;
}
```

Output on 64-bit OS/X:

```
The minimum value of LONG = -9223372036854775808
The maximum value of LONG = 9223372036854775807
The minimum value of LONG LONG = -9223372036854775808
The maximum value of LONG LONG = 9223372036854775807
9**13 = 2541865828329
```

Output on a 32-bit system or a recent 64-bit Windows OS, with a conformant C library:

```
The minimum value of LONG = -2147483648
The maximum value of LONG = 2147483647
The minimum value of LONG LONG = -9223372036854775808
The maximum value of LONG LONG = 9223372036854775807
9**13 = 2541865828329
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `9` is not a long int. You need first to convert all your 9s to `long`, so instead use:

```
printf("%ld",9L*9L*9L*9L*9L*9L*9L*9L*9L*9L*9L*9L*9L);
```

Comment: And if you need an 8-byte integer, you want LL.  On Windows x64 `long` is 4 bytes.

Comment: This will probably be as wrong as the sample in the question. You should instead use LL as specified by zzxyz.

Comment: @NiVeR: Yes, issues of portability and implementation-defined widths should be explained, but the question shows us the range of `long` in OP’s implementation, so we can see it suffices for them.